# WPF MediaElement - Preview Thumbnails on Hover Over the custom Slider

Tags: c#

I'm using a media element to play video and a custom slider to seek that video. Can I able to preview the thumbnails of video when I over the mouse on slider (as like in the you tube videos) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible, Media element doesn't have this feature. You can either find some library to generate the thumbnails for you or for example call FFMPEG console app which can do this – just let it [generate thumbnails](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video) and display the generated images according to mouse position while the mouse is hovering over the slider. It's quite advanced functionality.